# How can I remove the main-category from the URL of sub-category in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, category

We need to remove the main-category from the URL of sub-category in magento2.

--> Normal magento 2.0 category url structure:

www.domain.com/category/

www.domain.com/category/subcategory/

www.domain.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/

--> The structure should be:

www.domain.com/category/

www.domain.com/subcategory/

www.domain.com/subsubcategory/